# Limit OpenFileDialog's Multiselect

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a `OpenFileDialog` and its `MultiSelect` property is **ON**. My question is how can I limit the number of items to be selected, for example 5 items only?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the FileOk event to check the file(s) selected by the user when he clicks the OK button.  If you are not happy then display a message and set the CancelEventArgs.Cancel property to True to prevent the dialog from closing.  Like this:

```
    Dim dlg As New OpenFileDialog()
    dlg.Multiselect = True
    AddHandler dlg.FileOk, Sub(s, ce)
                               If dlg.FileNames.Length > 5 Then
                                   MessageBox.Show("Please select no more than 5 files")
                                   ce.Cancel = True
                               End If
                           End Sub
    If dlg.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        '' etc...
    End If
```

Comment: I have a problem with this. If I selected only 5 photos, the messagebox is still popping up. If i selected only 1 photo, the messagebox still shows

Comment: You must be doing it wrong, no idea what.  Use the debugger, look at the value of dlg.FileNames

Comment: where can I find the debugger? Sorry, but I'm new to VB

Comment: I already got it. I used `Filename` instead of `Filenames` sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. But you have alternatives:

**1.-** A good alternative could be to put all file names in a text file, and then accept that text file as your program's input.

**2.-** You should allow user to pick the directory. Then you list all the files and let them select as many files, there will not be any problem.

**3.-** You may have to use a `FolderBrowserDialog` instead and then use `IO.Directory.GetFiles`, which works properly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in feature for that in `OpenFileDialog` as far as I can see. Possible solution is to check `FileNames` returned from the dialog. If it count more than 5, for example, alert user and stop without operating the files.