# Specific number of item in OpenFileDialog

Tags: vb.net

Let's say I have an `OpenFileDialog` and it's `MultiSelect` property is **true**, and here's the list of what it needs to do.

- If the number of item is **greater than 5**, it will popup a message box saying that the max number of item is only 5.
- If the number of item selected is **less than 5**, let's say 4, it will say that you still need 1 item. If the selected number is 3, it will say you still need 2 items.
- It will only accept if the number of item selected is **exactly 5**

thanks :)

Comment: You [already know how to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808308/limit-openfiledialogs-multiselect).  Simply change the test to `<> 5`.  Do spend a *little* bit of time thinking about this, an If statement should not ever mystify a programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim numSelected = openFileDialog1.FileNames.Length
Dim message As String
Dim maxNumber = 5
Dim missing As Int32 = maxNumber - numSelected
If missing > 0 Then
    message = String.Format("You still need {0} items.", missing)
    MessageBox.Show(message)
ElseIf missing < 0 Then
    message = String.Format("Maximum number of selected items is {0}.", maxNumber)
    MessageBox.Show(message)
Else
    ' valid ... '
End If
```

Comment: Do I still need to use the code `If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then` for this?

Comment: @elvinguitar: if you want to show an `OpenFileDialog` you have to use `ShowDialog`, but you don't need to check the `DialogResult`. However, it doesn't hurt to do it anyway.

Comment: where should I insert the `If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then` ?